# Mac OS bug: click on file starts renaming

Tags: macos-catalina

I'm using Mac OS Catalina (10.15.5 - 19F101).
Sometimes when I click on a file once, the `Rename` mode gets enabled, as if the `Enter` button was pressed after the mouse click:

[image: rename mode enabled]

Is there a fix for this bug?

Comment: Are you sure you are not double clicking by mistake?

Comment: A double click opens the file instead of renaming it - even if the text part of the file icon is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, it's a 'feature' (whether you like it that way or not ;)

If it's already selected, a single click on the name will enable renaming.

If you don't want that to happen, click the icon not the name if the file is already selected.

Comment: On my Mac, sometimes renaming gets enabled even if the file was not already selected.

Comment: I can't repro that. Try on another account.

Comment: This bug occurs only a few times a week. Is it possible to disable onClick-renaming in MacOS settings?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware.